# Python: Filtering a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, tuples

I got a huge dictionary named `TempDict` which consists of several other dictionaries. It looks like this:

```
2556 {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Intern', 'ticket-closed': False, 'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 30, 59, 547747, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 30, 59, 547747, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'new')]}
2557 {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Intern', 'ticket-closed': False, 'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 32, 37, 491657, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 32, 37, 491657, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'new')]}
2558 {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Intern', 'ticket-closed': False, 'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 33, 51, 29451, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 33, 51, 29451, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'new')]}
2559 {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Intern', 'ticket-closed': False, 'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 37, 39, 205416, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 37, 39, 205416, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'new')]}
```

As you can see there is a tuple called `status-events`, which consists of a datetime object and a string like 'new'

```
(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 37, 39, 205416, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'new')
```

Now I want to save all elements, where the **first** status entry (it can have more entries than one) is from the year 2015, in a new dictionary named `TicketDict1`

I've tried it this way but `TempDict1` just stays empty.

```
for i in self.TempDict:
        for j,k in self.TempDict[i]['status-events']:
            if j.isocalendar()[0] == '2015':
                self.ticketDict1[i] = self.TempDict[i]
                break
```

Comment: status-events is not a tuple, but a list of tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using dictionary comprehension:

```
TicketDict1 = {key: value for key, value in TempDict.items() if 
               value["status-events"][0][0].year == 2015}
```

You can use [`.items()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_items.htm) to get a list of pairs `(key, value)` of your dictionary, then check if the first entry `value["status-events"][0][0]` is from the [`.year`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.year) you are looking for.

Comment: I think there is one more level of nesting... `value["status-events"][0][0]`

Comment: You don't need parentheses around `key, value`.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos I thought it might be more readable but you are right, this is probably better without, thank you.

Comment: good idea .. but it still doesnt work for me. TempDict stays empty.

Comment: @k.troy2012 Then something is wrong with your data because I tested it locally and it workds just fine.

Comment: @k.troy2012 Look at [this sample](https://ideone.com/vO0TxC). This is the expected result (I modified some years), isn't it?

Comment: yes it works now! thanks .. I had a small typo in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the dictionary's entries are lists, so the [Delgan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33807596/1197008) solution raise a TypeError exception when I tried it (maybe I misunderstood something).

Reading the data, I assume that TempDict is a list of dictionaries, if that so the following is the one line solution using list comprehension

```
TicketDict1 = [value for value in TempDict if isinstance(value["status-events"], list) and value["status-events"][0][0].year == 2015]
```

however, I do not like to duplicate code (`value["status-events"]` is written twice), so I would prefer the following, longer, solution

```
TicketDict1 = []
for value in TempDict:
    entry = value["status-events"]
    if isinstance(entry, list) and entry[0][0].year == 2015:
        TicketDict1.append(value)
```

Comment: File "/media/sf_Projects/Ticketauswertung/Converting.py", line 30, in ConvertData
    entry = value["status-events"]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: This means that not all the entries in TempDict are dictionaries.
I can not comment on your first question, could you better explain the type/structure of TempDict?

Comment: TempDict is a dictionary which consists of these tickets.

Comment: Delgan has aready posted the right solution for me above. thanks anyway.